# JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data laravel

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel

Hello I have a problem when I wanna show my query result at my text fields 
I tried to don't use JSON.parse but when I do it this doesn't show anything then I use an alert and show my **undefined** 
this is the code using an alert to show the result

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#zip_code').blur(function()
    {
        var zip_code=$(this).val();
        if(zip_code != '')
        {
            var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
            $.ajax({
                url:"{{route('complete.zip')}}",
                method:"POST",
                data:{zip_code:zip_code,_token:_token},
                success:function(data)
                {
                    alert(data.value1);

                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

when I try to convert the JSON in the console show me it
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
this is the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#zip_code').blur(function()
    {
        var zip_code=$(this).val();
        if(zip_code != '')
        {
            var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
            $.ajax({
                url:"{{route('complete.zip')}}",
                method:"POST",
                data:{zip_code:zip_code,_token:_token},
                success:function(data)
                {
                    var result = JSON.parse(data);
                   $('#estado').val(result.value1);
                   $('#municipio').val(result.value2);

                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

the PHP files is the next 
 use DB;
class ClientBusinessController extends Controller
{

```
public function index()
{

    return view("new_client.register_business");
}

public function receiveValueZip(Request $request)
{   
    if(!empty($request->get('zip_code')))
    {

        $result=DB::table('direccion')
        ->select('Calle1','Calle2')
        ->where('Id_Direccion','=',6)
        ->get();
        foreach($result as $r)
        {
            json_encode(array("value1"=>$r->Calle1,"value2"=>$r->Calle2));

        }
    } 
}
```

Does someone know how to resolve this problem? thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call `json_encode` multiple times you end up with invalid JSON. You should instead construct your array structure fully and call `json_encode` only once. However I recommend using `response()->json` and letting Laravel handle the JSON serialization:

```
public function index()
{

    return view("new_client.register_business");
}

public function receiveValueZip(Request $request)
{   
    if(!empty($request->get('zip_code')))
    {

        $result=DB::table('direccion')
        ->select('Calle1','Calle2')
        ->where('Id_Direccion','=',6)
        ->get();
        return response()->json(
            $result->map(function ($row) {
                return array("value1"=>$r->Calle1,"value2"=>$r->Calle2);
            });
        );

    } 
}
```